# How to create a Curved edge between two vertices?

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to simply make an Edge curved, preferably such that I can click and drag the mouse to easily control where and how much it curves. How can this be achieved?

[image: e,]

Comment: An edge is a  linear two point line segment that connects two vertices. It cannot by definition be curved.

Comment: .. but you could make a Bezier Curve between 2 points, adjust its control handles, and then convert it to a mesh.

Comment: Thanks, the Bezier Curve sounds like what I need. Please, how do you create a Bezier Curve between vertices?